# PhotoSwipe: Disable Image Zoom-in and Zoom-out Animation

Tags: photoswipe

I want to disable the animation effect when clicking / double-tapping an image in PhotoSwipe, how can I achieve this? I checked PhotoSwipe options but didn't find anything there. I also checked other questions here in StackOverflow but didn't find a similar question.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/gbadPv

On the browser developer console I noticed that the zooming uses `transform: translate3d(...);` - I believe this is what causes the animation